# how to avoid keyboard in textfields

Tags: swift

I use a couple of buttons '0123456789.' (and some others) as an alternative for a keyboard. They are connected to (several) texfields. I made them all programmatically, so without storyboard. I also use UITextFieldDelegate. That works as expected, and I can input my text into the textfields.

I use the following code for my buttons:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    activeField = textField
}

@IBAction func Pressed(sender: UIButton) {
    if (activeField != nil) {
        switch sender.tag {
        case 0:
            activeField!.text = activeField!.text+"0"
        case 1:
```

The problem is that every-time I click in a textfield, the keyboard opens up too. I want to avoid that... since I made an alternative for input with the buttons. How can I get rid of the keyboard when I click in a textfield?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just return `NO` from `textFieldShouldBeginEditing:` from the delegate you mention you are already using.

> When the user performs an action that would normally initiate an editing session, the text field calls this method first to see if editing should actually proceed. In most circumstances, you would simply return YES from this method to allow editing to proceed.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField == /* a text field that is using your custom layout */)
        return NO;
}
```

<sup>[[Source]](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textFieldShouldBeginEditing:)</sup>

Though why don't you just use `[textField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad];`

Comment: James, thanks. but when I use textFieldShouldBeginEditing not only the keyboard is gone... but  also I can't use the following code anymore:     'func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        activeField = textField
    }
    
    @IBAction func Pressed(sender: UIButton) {
        println("test")
        if (activeField != nil) {
            switch sender.tag {
            case 0:
                activeField!.text = activeField!.text+"0"
            case 1: etc '

Comment: You might have look at keeping a reference to your active field, using `resignFirstResponder` and editing the text in the field manually. However this has a bit of a code 'smell'. You might do better to make a custom view and use `textField.inputView`

Comment: APIs are much simpler use and when you follow the intended patterns. Code maintenance also becomes an issue when you don't.

Comment: a custom view? that sounds like a great idea... but that is new territory for me. I'm going to look for some examples. if you have more tips I would be glad to hear them. Thanks, Jan

Comment: (You can mark code with backticks `\`code here\`` ) (But backpacks themselves are quite annoying to include in code!)

Comment: The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextField/inputView) is always a good place to start

Comment: Thanks James, I learned a lot. My most important lesson is to follow the intended patterns and use the API ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You should make your custom keypad the inputView of the textField. It will then be shown instead of the built-in keyboard.

i.e.:

```
textField.inputView = yourCustomKeypad;
```

Comment: sorry... when I reread my question I see why you advise that. I didn't make a keyboard... just added buttons that I use as a keypad. I did that because I also have integrated other buttons with specific tasks. I will edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a similar input interface, using custom buttons...why not instead of a `UITextField`, use a `UILabel` to display the "8,900"(input).

Then just make the buttons manipulate the `UILabel.text`.

Comment: Hi Dustin, then I need 30 UILabels... and my problem will be how to select the right UILabel to receive the input. Do you know an intuitive way to solve that? thanks, Jan

Comment: so right now you have 30 textFields? you can set tag of each UILabel (0-30)

Comment: you could place the 30 UILabels in an array accordingly [0-29], place an invisible button over each UILabel with respective tag [0-29]. Make a global `var currentTag = Int()`, each `@IBaction func button(sender: UIButton) { currentTag = sender.tag}...then in your custom keypad button actions `{(UILabelArray[currentTag] as! UILabel). text = "whatever"}`